# React-spring анимация после анимации

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как с помощю библиотеки react-spring или просто с помощю react и css , сделать анимацию после анимации.К примеру у меня есть div и я хочу сначала увеличить его а потом вернуть к обратному размеру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так для этого `react-spring` не нужен чистый `css` стандартный `keyframes`

[**Codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-wave-8twvm)

```
.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-animation: scaling 3s;
  animation: scaling 3s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaling {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Еще сделал вариант с **React-spring** ссылка [**тут**](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-blackwell-x8e03)

```
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(true);
  const props = useSpring({ x: state ? 1 : 0, config: { duration: 1000 } });

  useEffect(_ => {
    setState(!state);
  }, []);

  return (
    <animated.div
      className="box"
      style={{
        transform: props.x
          .interpolate({
            range: [0, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
            output: [1, 1.5, 2, 1]
          })
          .interpolate(x => `scale(${x})`)
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: А как эту css анимацию вызвать в реакте?

Comment: @SteelSquirrel1894 наверху есть ссылка на пример .

Comment: Уже разобрался просто когда ты добавляешь анимацию в приложениее созданым через create-react-app нужно прописывать @keyframes а не @-webkit-keyframes

Comment: @SteelSquirrel1894 без разницы это префикс (хрома) можно и так и так.Примите ответ нажав на галочку если оно помогло решить вашу проблему

Comment: Да решило.Спасибо ^_^